# Handling Null in WriteXml

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq, reflection, datatable

For converting Linq to DataTable I am using the following Extension Method (**Taken from Stackoverflow)**

**Linq to DataTable**

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
 {
      DataTable table = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
      PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                    BindingFlags.Instance);
      foreach (var prop in props)
        {
           Type propType = prop.PropertyType;
           // Is it a nullable type? Get the underlying type 
           if (propType.IsGenericType && 
               propType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
               propType = new NullableConverter(propType).UnderlyingType;
                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, propType);
            }

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                var values = new object[props.Length];
                for (var i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
                        values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                table.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            return table;
        }
```

**WriteXml**

```
    PersonDB.PersonDataContext con = new PersonDB.PersonDataContext();
    DataTable tb = new DataTable();
    tb = con.Persons.ToDataTable();
    tb.WriteXml(@"d:\temp\Person.xml");
```

**Question**

---

The Extension Method creates XML file, but for null values no element is created in XML file. It say if Commission field is null then commission element is missing in Xml generation.

I want to insert element with empty string for null values (ref type) and (0.00) for decimals and (0) for integers. Where do I need to make the change?

Answer (score 2):

I would create an extension method for DataTable which does that:

```
public static DataTable ZeroNullValues(this DataTable dataTable)
{
    foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<dataTable.Columns.Count;i++)
        {
            if(row[i] == null)
            {
                Type columnType = dataTable.Columns[i].DataType;
                if(columnType == typeof(string))
                {
                    row[i] = string.Empty;
                }
                else if(columnType == typeof(int) || columnType == typeof(long))
                {
                    row[i] = 0;
                }
                else if(columnType == typeof(float) || columnType == typeof(double))
                {
                    row[i] = 0.00F;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return dataTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912723/dataset-writexml-does-not-write-an-empty-tag-if-the-field-was-empty-c-sharp/14857387#14857387):

You can use WriteXmlSchema (and ReadXmlSchema) to store the schema for the table. This will mean that although the NULL columns are not included in the XML, they are still correctly imported.

```
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(QUERY, CONNECTION))
{
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
    dataSet.WriteXmlSchema(@"C:\TEMP\Schema.xsd");
    dataSet.Tables[0].WriteXml(@"C:\TEMP\Output.xml");
}
```

There's a really useful article on it here:[Save Dataset to XML With Null Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912723/dataset-writexml-does-not-write-an-empty-tag-if-the-field-was-empty-c-sharp/14857387#14857387)